# Pythonic way to perform <,>,==,<=, or >= operation based on value of a string?

Tags: python

Supposed I have a string `op` that can be equal to <, >, ==, <=, or >=.

I want to perform the associated operation on two values. Is there a more pythonic way to do that than the simple if/else approach shown below?

```
def doit(op, val1, val2):
     if op == ">":
         return val1 > val2
     elif op == "<":
         return val1 < val2
     etc....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `operator`:

```
import operator
operations = {'>':'gt', '>=':'ge', '<':'lt', '==':'eq', '!=':'ne', '<=':'le'}
def doit(op, *vals):
  return getattr(operator, operations[op])(*vals)
```

Using `getattr` is the equivalent of calling `operator.eq`, `operator.lt`, etc, except that the string name of the function to be called is passed to `getattr`.

**Edit**: An even shorter solution entails importing specific functions from `operator`:

```
from operator import gt, ge, lt, eq, ne, le
operations = {'>':gt, '>=':ge, '<':lt, '==':eq, '!=':ne, '<=':le}
def doit(op, *vals):
  return operations[op](*vals)
```

Answer (score 3):

The second version in [Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50381436/908494) is probably what you actually want, but, just for fun, you can even dynamically pull the operators out of the `operator` functions:

```
import inspect
import operator
import re

ops = inspect.getmembers(operator, callable)
pubops = (op for opname, op in ops if not opname.startswith('_'))
opmatches = ((op, re.search('ame as a\s*(.*?)\s*b\.', op.__doc__)) for op in pubops)
operations = {match.group(1): op for op, match in opmatches if match}
```

Now `operations` has not only the comparison operators, but *every* operator that can be overridden.

I'm not sure what this is useful for.<sup>1</sup> (I did say you probably want Ajax's answer.) But it was fun to slap together.

---

<sub>1. Best I can come up with: With a few more lines of code (using `ast`), you could write an `opexpr_eval` that only allows parenthesized operator expressions of `literal_eval`-able values and nothing else, which would be no more dangerous than `literal_eval` itself. (Even then, I'm not sure what good the iops will do you. Or matmul, since numpy arrays aren't literal-eval-able. But you can have fun testing whether `(1, (2, 3)) is (1, (2, 3))`. :)</sub>